# Compare C char and char*

Tags: c, arduino, compare

I have a two dimensional array (commandNames} that I am searching to find a match with a single char which is read from the Arduino Serial input. The comparison code isn't working.

```
const char* commandNames[COMMAND_COUNT][4] = {
    { "STOP",           "p", "M", "0" },
    { "STOP LEFT",      "s", "M", "9" },
    { "STOP RIGHT",     "S", "M", "10" },
    { "FORWARD",        "f", "M", "1" },
...
};

char command = Serial.read();
for (int i = 0; i < COMMAND_COUNT; i++) {
    char *cmd = (char*)commandNames[i][1];
    if (command == (char)cmd) { <-- Need help with this line 
... we have a match...
```

The line "if (command == (char)cmd)" is the problem.

Comment: `cmd` is a *pointer* to a `char`. You try to compare `command` to the *pointer*. Now think a little, how can you get a single `char` element from a string?

Comment: The programmer dude was faster. I agree that this will solve ayour problem.

Comment: The answer from iBug (see below) shows that my question was clear and easily understandable and not "off topic"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're just comparing a character given from sorta input with a 1-char string. So you just dereference the pointer and compare the character:

```
command == *cmd
           ^
```

And since `cmd` is of type `char*`, there's no need for type casting again, so I dropped the cast (`(char)`).

As [xander noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901772/compare-c-char-and-char/48901885#comment84809081_48901885), `char cmd = commandNames[i][1][0]` is better in terms of readability.

As a side note, `char *cmd = (char*)commandNames[i][1]` is some dangerous code. You're casting pointer to a string literal to a modifiable pointer (dropping the `const` modifier). Since you don't need to modify `cmd`, it's better to declare and define it as `const char*`, and drop the conversion on the right-hand side (RHS).

Comment: For better understanding `char cmd = commandNames[i][1][0]` should also work.

Comment: Thanks - simple answer that worked immediately.